# DRCSIM: gazebo crashes when model launced as "pinned"

Tags: drcsim, gazebo-1.3

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm using the drc simulator and I've recently updated to gazebo 1.3, since then I encounter the following problem:

If I try to "pin" the robot model too early (publish "pinned" to /mode either from the launch file or from the command line) gazebo crashes.
If I wait a little before I publish the message everything seems to work fine.

I also noticed that even though I launch my model with no position controllers started it still stays in a stiff position for several seconds before it collapses, perhaps this is the time when a pin command will crash the simulator?

Any idea what might be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/478/drcsim:-gazebo-crashes-when-model-launced-as-%22pinned%22/) by [EricSidorov](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/116/ericsidorov/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The DRCRobotPlugin unpins the simulation automatically after 10s.

There was one bug fixed already regarding the mode setting:
[code fix](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/45/fix-issue-56-fix-some-deprecated-warnings)

Of course you'd have to build from source or wait for the next release to get this fix.

---

Originally posted by [RoboUser](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/88/robouser/) with karma: 36 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1